# Javascript - Detecting Refresh - onload AND onunload - Could you use them both to detect refresh?

Tags: javascript, page-refresh

Is there any way to detect a refresh in Javascript?
I look some things up on internet. Very complicated things like session cookies ClientX/ClientY. Found nothing but a big complicated mess...
Then I thought something, with onload, the code is always executed if the page loads. *So it also will be executed on a reload* But then, the code you want to be executed only when the page reloads, not when it just loads. 
When you use onunload then the code inside the onunload will execute when closing window, backspace and refresh.

1. onload

   - loading a page
   - refresh
   - other??
2. onunload

   - closing browser
   - refresh
   - backspace

As you can see, when I use onload, it will load the page etc. And with onunload it will do things when closing browser refresh etc.
Is it possible, to only do things with the refresh when both of the events (onload and onunload) are triggered?

PS: I might be totally wrong, but I just had this idea, does/could it work?

Comment: I doubt it - the reloaded page's OnLoad event would be running 'fresh' without access to anything your OnUnLoad event could save without something that persisted between pages, like a cookie

Comment: I tend to think if you are depending on browser behavior like onunload and refresh, You're Doing it Wrong (TM).  It's just too unreliable in the general case.  For example, if the user's browser crashes, onunload will never be called.

Comment: @n8wrl And if you do onunload first and in the onunload you trigger the onload? Could it work then?

Comment: @mellamokb In my case, the onunload doesnt have to be called when browser crashes. I think...

Comment: Why do you want to detect a refresh? What is the purpose? I'm asking you because maybe what you are trying to do could be achieved in a different way.

Comment: @ADASein I'm trying to make a one-href more-pages website (one website URL but more pages by means of css display:block/none) Everything works fine, but when I refresh the browser window, the content stays the same, but the menu (when active menu) it changes back to the first menu.

Comment: Are you able to use session variables? you can have a session variable that increment everytime the page is loaded and display content according with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not rely on the `onbeforeunload` event; use `onload` event and `localStorage`/`sessionStorage`.

```
var visited = false;
window.onload = function () {
    if (localStorage["visited"] === true) {
        visited = true;
    }
    localStorage["visited"] = true;
    /* change `local` to `session` if you want
       this behavior to stay for the present session only */
    return;
}
```

This adds a flag on the client side in HTML5's `localStorage` system. This would be preserved after page reload/browser crash/tab close - reopen too.

What the code basically does is to see if that flag is already set or not. If it is set, it means that the user has visited the page before. We then set a global variable called `visited` to true. You can check for this variable in your code, and if it is true, then stop the execution of the script.

```
if (visited === true) {
    return false; //return breaks out of your function
}
```

You might want to wrap your code in a single IIFE which will execute only if this variable is falsy.

```
!visited && (function() {
    //your code here
})();
```

**THIS METHOD (OR ANY METHOD, FOR THAT MATTER) IS NOT FOOL PROOF. USE THIS ONLY TO BETTER USER EXPERIENCE AND NOT TO PREVENT MALICIOUS ACTIVITY. ANY USER CAN EASILY CLEAR OR EDIT `localStorage` DATA.**

Comment: How are you going to tell "visited" from a refresh from "visited" from, well, visiting the site again days later?

Comment: This should use `sessionStorage` so it's specific to a single tab, and, if `visited===true` the flag should be cleared, `storage.removeItem(visisted)`